# MYSQL ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1111

There are two tables

1. project(project_id, project_name, project_city);
2. assignment(employee_id, employee_name, duration);

Now I have to find in which project maximum number of employee is assigned.
I have write a sql query

```
SELECT MAX(COUNT(employee_id)) from assignment group by project_id;
```

but this query is giving the following error:

ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function. I am using mySql.

Comment: Show example input and output data.

Comment: Based on your information, it seems that your `assignment` table, doens't have a `project_id` field.....

Comment: Sorry it will be project_id instead of employee name

Comment: You can't do MAX(COUNT()).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get what you want is `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT COUNT(employee_id) as cnt
FROM assignment 
GROUP BY project_id
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Is `ORDER BY` necessary when limiting the result set to a single result...?

Comment: @Anovative . . . It is necessary if you want to get the largest value.  Otherwise, you'll get an arbitrary value from the aggregated results.